# starting mysql without procedures

Tags: mysql, tokudb

I am getting the following error and **tokudb** does not start.
I restored the data from some other server / version and now the proc table column count is different.

```
131119 16:53:44 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'comment' at position 15 to have type text, found type char(64).
ERROR: 1136  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
131119 16:53:44 [ERROR] Aborting

131119 16:53:44 [Note] ./bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How do I start mysql (tokudb)? I do not need the stored procedures.

Comment: please check this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59364

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59364

There is a comment from Peter Laursen

```
"start the server with the --skip-grant-tables option to cause it to skip the normal grant table checks, then run mysql_upgrade. ... Then stop the server and restart it normally."
```

Reference URL from the bug report was: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-7.html

Comment: Agreed, mysql_upgrade FTW.